# How to change SVG fill color on second click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the fill color on SVG on the second click, currently, am able to ad fill color on the first click, but I want the color to change/reset to default on second click;
This is my current code:

```
jQuery('#color-my-svg').on("click", function() {
  if(!jQuery(this)[0].hasAttribute('style')){
    jQuery('#color-my-svg').css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
  }
  else{
    jQuery(this).removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a click counter as a `variable` & check add/remove a class depending on the number of clicks like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divId" class="divClass">I'm a div!</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Styling for demo only */
.divClass {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.svg-fill-color {
  background: red;
  /* Add fill here */
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
let clickNumbers = 0;

jQuery('#divId').on("click", function() {
        clickNumbers++;

    if(clickNumbers % 2 == 0){
        jQuery('#divId').addClass('svg-fill-color');
    } else {
        jQuery('#divId').removeClass('svg-fill-color');
    }
});
```

You can check the sample code **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/s5q4fdpt/)**.

Let me know, if that helps!

Comment: Although it doesn't factor the first click, it works fine. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the user clicks on the element:

- Change fill color iff the element has the class identifier(say
  `click-one`).
- Else add the class identifier.

---

```
jQuery('#color-my-svg').on("click", function() {
  if(jQuery('#color-my-svg').hasClass("click-one")) 
    jQuery('#color-my-svg').css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
  else 
    jQuery('#color-my-svg').addClass("click-one");
});
```

Comment: I forgot to remove your part! Welcome to Stack Overflow